# No GPS position in QField

Tags: gps, qfield

In qfield, I cannot get gps information to work. If I press the gps button, the map freezes and cannot be moved any longer. The gps status bar does not show any positioning value (X: N.a. ...). Without positioning information qfield works fine, but accurate positioning information is a crucial feature of a gis for field use.

I am using qfield 1.0.0-rc5 on a samsung tablet (galaxy tab active2, Android 8.0). The tablet's gps does its job. I have tested it with different apps. The CRS of the gis project is EPSG:25832 (ETRS89/UTM zone 32N) and the original qgis project was synced with qfieldsync (QGIS Version: 3.6.0.).
I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Does it work if you use WGS84 EPSG:4326?

Comment: I transformed the project to EPSG:31467 (GK3, Gauss-Krüger zone 3) and to EPSG:4326 (WGS84). With GK3, the same: no positioning information, freezing of the map. But with WGS 84 qfield runs correctly, quite the way it should.

Comment: I then reinstalled qfield and now everything works. I have tested 3 CRS so far, without any problems.

Comment: Good to hear. Probably best to answer your own question with that.